# Origins of Mathematical Symbols/Names

Tags: soft-question, notation

I'm not sure if this has been asked. I'll explain the question by an example.

Fields are often denoted by the letter k, which comes from the German word Körper, meaning body (like corpse, corporeal).

Most mathematical symbols relate directly or indirectly to the English names, so what other exceptions are there?

(Yes, this is inspired by the other post about languages in math)

Comment: On a somewhat unrelated note, I only learned recently that the words manifold and variety are synonymous. The former is German, and the latter is French (I might be wrong). The French would call differential manifold "variété différentielle," while algebraic variety is just "variété algébrique."

Comment: Let me add to this question: what is the origin of the word "ring"?

Comment: Interesting! I had always assumed that K stood for something like "Kampen"... which, as I just found out, is not actually a German word. :P

Comment: In Spanish is the same as in French: we say "variedad" either for a manifold or an (algebraic, "algebraica") variety.

Comment: Some cognate of (English word) "variety" is "manifold" in all the Romance languages. "Manifold" comes from Germann, I believe actually from Riemann.

Comment: I'm puzzled by variety and manifold; they aren't really synonyms or cognates. In common usage, manifold is sometimes similar to varieties (plural) but not variety (singular). Can someone clarify how these two words got intertwined?

Comment: Ah, the German *Mannigfaltigkeit* apparently means both variety and manifold. ("Mathematicians are like Frenchmen: whatever you say to them they translate into their own language and forthwith it is something entirely different" - Goethe)

Comment: In German "mannigfaltig" means of great variety; besides its noun "Mannigfaltigkeit" that denotes the diversity as an "object of thinking" there is also the noun "Varietät" which however refers to a single variant  in a "Mannigfaltigkeit". One should be cautioned that the German "Variete" means cabaret and not variety.

Answer (score 16):

$\mathbb{Z}$ comes from the German "Zahlen" which means "numbers".

Answer (score 16):

Center of a group is denoted Z, from German word Zentrum

Answer (score 16):

As an undergraduate, I was told that $V$ is often used to denote a neighborhood because the French translation is *voisinage*. Anyone else hear this?

Comment: Yes, I think this is true. And U is for 'Umgebung', the German word for neighborhood.

Comment: And U and V are consecutive letters, making them especially convenient for using to represent two neighborhoods that occur together.   One often sees, say, a function f: U -> V where U and V are open subsets of A and B, respectively.

Comment: @Arminius: I hope I don't double post. Was having trouble posting earlier, but I did not know that. Thanks. 

Answer (score 16):

This one is pretty well-known: the notation $e$ for the identity of a group comes from the German word *Einheit*, meaning *unit*.

I'd be willing to bet that the notation $G$ for a group also comes from German... but we don't notice, because the German word for *group* is *Gruppe*!

---

[Here's a fun one](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partition+function): the notation $Z$ for a topological quantum field theory comes indirectly from the notation $Z$ for a partition function in statistical mechanics, which comes from the German word *Zustandssumme*, meaning *state sum*. I said "indirectly" because partition function in quantum field theory isn't a statistical-mechanical partition function... it just looks like one after you Wick rotate! (Then again, maybe there's a deeper sense in which the QFT partition function really *is* a statistical-mechanical partition function. Does anybody know?)

Comment: Who was the first to use $Z$ for a partition function?

Comment: Related: [Why is the identity element of a group denoted by $e$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/87794)

Answer (score 15):

I've been told that the notation $\mathcal{O}$ for the structure sheaf of a scheme/variety/whatever comes from the Italian word "olomorfo/olomorfa" for "holomorphic".

I should note that I don't have any evidence for this claim beyond "I heard it somewhere from somebody". It would be great if anybody could corroborate this.

Comment: Great! I always wondered where this comes from.

Comment: This is new for me!! cool!!

Comment: finally I know why this letter is used :)

Comment: I used to believe that the O came as the geometrical approximation of a physical ring, from the local ring idea.

Comment: Um, can someone point to an actual reference justifying this? Why would a letter from an Italian word be used here when the topic was systematically developed by the French? It feels like an artificial  etymology (and Kevin is conceding he has no source on this, but people's willingness to believe it surprises me). I once heard O was in honor of Oka. Hmm... *Perhaps* O is related to the very long (since 1870s) tradition of using O for rings in number theory, which was based on Dedekind's term for a ring: order, or rather Ordnung in German. He wrote fraktur o a lot in his work.

Answer (score 11):

The notation $\mathcal{F}$ for sheaves comes from the French word "faisceau" meaning "bundle".

Also "gerbe" means "sheaf" in French.

Comment: It's in fact the same etymology for "fascism". Go look up your Roman history for why "bundles" have anything to do with government.

Comment: Indeed wikipedia has a brief explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascism#Etymology

Comment: I've always liked to translate "gerbe" as "bouquet" or "wreath", though my French isn't good enough to say which is closer to the meaning in French.

Comment: I don't know either, but "Garbe" in German means "sheaf" (in mathematics and otherwise). "Garbe" at least superficially looks like it could be related to "gerbe"...

Comment: btw, I don't know if I recalled the following correctly: "faisceau" are tranlated as "stack" in early papers of Atiyah in the 1950s... Maybe in the one joint with Hodge on 2nd differential forms on algebraic varieties.

Comment: Yeah, one of the definitions of "faisceau" in my French dictionary is "stack", as in a stack of arms. Arms as in weaponry, I guess.

Comment: Surely a native French speaker will read this? I'm not one, but I thought the French noun _gerbe_ meant "spray", as in a spray (bouquet) of flowers.  This also explains why _gerber_ is slang for "to vomit".   

Comment: In French, the word "gerbe" commonly refers to an arrangement of wheat like this http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/H%C3%A9raldique_meuble_Gerbe_de_bl%C3%A9.svg/420px-H%C3%A9raldique_meuble_Gerbe_de_bl%C3%A9.svg.png

Comment: Ah, thanks François.  That's definitely a sheaf, or indeed a wheatsheaf, then.

Comment: I can't think of an English word that exactly matches the common usage of *faisceau* in French; I could use any of cone, beam, ray, spray, jet, stream, or sheaf (thanks to Tom) depending on context. The best description I can come up with is: things tied together in a directed way. It has lots of uses from light ray (*faisceau lumineux*) to muscle fibres (*faisceau musculaire*).

Answer (score 10):

You might like to take a look at this site:

[Earliest Uses of Various Mathematical Symbols](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathsym.html)

Answer (score 10):

I've heard that the "$K$" of $K$-theory comes from the German word "Klasse(n)" meaning "class(es)", but I don't have any concrete evidence for this.

Comment: Now I'm wondering why class field theory was not called K-field theory...

Comment: It is stated in the first paragraph of this introduction by Karoubi: http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0602/0602082.pdf

Comment: I think this is also mentioned at the beginning of Rosenberg's book on K-theory.

Answer (score 8):

In homological algebra, one sometimes uses Z and B to denote cycles (or closed form) and boundaries (or exact forms), respectively. Z must be for Zycle.

Comment: Z is for "Zykel" which means cycles, and B is for "Bilder" which means "images". (I'm german and that is what I learned in my german algebraic topology class)

Comment: Probably one reason for using the first letters of the German words here is that in English 'cycle' and 'chains' have the same first letter.

Comment: Also, *boundary* is *Rand* in german, with *boundaries* translating to *Ränder*.

Comment: Related: [What is the historical origin for the use of the symbol ∂ in topology?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/204483)

Answer (score 8):

$\mathbb{N}$ comes from the German "Natürliche Zahlen"=natural number
$\mathbb{Z}$ comes from the German "ganZe Zahl"=integer numbers
$\mathbb{Q}$ comes from the Latin "Quotient"= result of a division
$\mathbb{R}$ comes from the German "Reelle Zahl"=real numbers
$\mathbb{C}$ comes from the French "nombre Complexe"=complex numbers

Comment: maybe \mathbb R comes from the french "nombres reelles" or the english "real numbers" instead? how do you know? For complex numbers, I would even argue for a german/latin origin, since germans used "complex" instead of "komplex" at the time of Gauss.

Comment: I was under the impression that Q, R, C are all from French (Quotient, Réel, Complexe). I doubt the Romans needed a symbol for Q...

Comment: Apparently Z, Q, R are all eventually due to Bourbaki and stand for the German *Zahlen*, *Quotient*, *Reelle*. However, they were all randomly used by someone else before... http://jeff560.tripod.com/nth.html

Comment: The word Quotient is actually a Latin word, inherited by many modern languages.

Answer (score 6):

The letter $T$ in the names for the separation axioms $T_1$, $T_2$, etc
in point set topology comes from "Trennungsaxiom" in German.
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trennungsaxiom

Answer (score 5):

There is a "classic" book about the history of mathematical notations by Florian Cajori though there has been some "revision" of his work by more recent scholars.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florian_Cajori

Comment: Why did you put the word revision in quotes?

Comment: Some but not all have taken issue with some of Cajori's scholarship.

Answer (score 5):

I [asked a while ago](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19264/what-is-the-etymology-for-the-term-conductor) about the etymology of the name *conductor*. Often the conductor of an order in a number field is denoted by $\mathfrak f$. This comes from the original German name *Führer* given by Dedekind.

Answer (score 5):

Oh, but of course $\emptyset$ comes from Bourbaki.  Interestingly, so does $\Rightarrow$ to denote implication, and $\in$ instead of $\varepsilon$.  The "Dangerous bend" comes from Bourbaki as well.

However, my all time favorite is the set of associated primes of a module M.  $Ass(M)$ is in fact called the *assassinator* of $M$, and its elements are called *assassins*.

Comment: In particular $\emptyset$ is due to André Weil, yet in comparison with other marks he has left on mathematics, it is the most vacuous.

Comment: I enjoyed the wordplay, Zavosh. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, I had always assumed that "dangerous bend" was due to Knuth! But you are correct: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbaki_dangerous_bend_symbol

Comment: $Ass$ doesn't sound polite in modern English though...

Answer (score 3):

$x,y,z$, and in particular that $x$ is the independent variable and $y$ the dependent variable, are due to Descartes, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Did he choose these letters more or less at random, or did he have some particular reason for the choice?

Comment: Well, now I'm not sure.  Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes credits Descartes with suggesting $x^2$ for "$x$ times $x$".  Leibniz invented the words "coordinate, abscissa, ordinate".

Comment: I once heard that the typesetter of Descartes' book on geometry asked him whether any particular choice of letters is important and when Descartes replied that it is not, he suggested to use x and y because they are rarely used in French and so he will not run out of them when he typesets the book.

Comment: Dmitri: Interesting! I wonder if anybody can corroborate this story.

Comment: @KevinH.Lin Apparently not, cf. [Explanation why $x, y, z$ are always variables](//mathoverflow.net/q/30307).

Answer (score 2):

> Utile erit scribit ∫ pro omnia.
>   (It is useful to write ∫ instead of omnia)
>   – Leibniz (1675-10-29)

(Source for this quotiation: Eriksson, Estep, Hansbo, Johnson: Computational differential equations, end of Ch. 3)

In response to some comments: *omnis* [means “all”](http://www.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/lookup.pl?stem=omnis&ending=). Compare *omnivore*. Here endeth the Latin lesson.

Comment: What is "omnia"?

Comment: Also, I think the $\int$ symbol is supposed to be an elongated "S", which is supposed to stand for "summa"(?) in Latin(?), meaning "sum".

Comment: I guess integrating is stretching the notion of sum :)

Comment: It's meant to be Greek to Latin: $\Sigma\to\int$ $\Delta\to d$

Comment: I'm assuming omnia (literally all, I think) is used to mean something along the lines of "sum".

Comment: IIRC, omnia also means total.

Comment: In Latin, "pro" is an adverb which means "in favour of", but also "before", "in front of"; and "omnia" is a neutral plural which means "all the things". I don't know whether the word "omnia", in the 17th century Latin, used to denote sums/integrals or not. 

Comment: "Omnis, -e" is just the corresponding adjective.

Comment: Also, "erit" is the future of "to be". And the expression "utile erit scribit" doesn't look very correct to me. Perhaps it was "Utile erit scrib*ere*..."? 

Comment: @UG: Maybe "We will find it useful to write..."?

Answer (score 2):

*F* for a closed set comes from the French *ferme* (=firm, cf. *fermer*=to close).

What about *G* for an open set? Is this also an example of the next-letter phenomenon? (as in Michael's comment to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8295/origins-of-mathematical-symbols-names/8303#8303) to the question.)

Comment: According to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set) it comes from the German word Gebiet.

Comment: You're confusing *fermé* (closed) with *ferme* (firm, rigid); the accent makes a big difference!

Comment: Touche       ;)

Comment: You mean touché . Touche without accent is not an adjective but the word for a piano key, the equivalent of the english "touch" as in "the painter's delicate touch" or a hit on a target.

Comment: No, I don't; note the emoticon. (On the other hand, ferme was a mistake.)

Answer (score 1):

Pat Ballew's blog [Math Words](http://www.pballew.net/etyindex.html) has interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is sometimes used for vector spaces, from the French word "espace"="space".

Comment: Could also be Euclid.

Comment: @François: that's more likely for Euclidean space $\operatorname{E}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram has nice a little paragraph on the history of the term "Ring" right after the list of ring axioms.

[Ring (from Wolfram Mathworld)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ring.html)

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that. That does not explain *why* 'ring' was chosen, though.

Comment: I think it mentions on there that "ring" comes from the cyclic structure you get in many rings, e.g. successive powers of the same element in $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Certainly thanks to the chosen word (ring, anneau in french) I have always thought of a ring as a torus, like the product of one operation (+) by the other (x) and closed in these two dimensions. I guess that I would also like to see sub-rings and modules as small rings with the initial ring like a thread passing in their holes.  

Comment: This is a false etymology. Everyone thinks it's from cycling in modular arithmetic (I once did), but please look at 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35286/origins-of-names-of-algebraic-structures 
for the correct history of the term ring. 

Answer (score 0):

In design theory we talk of a t-(v,k,λ). I think v originally meant "varieties", but I don't know if any of the other symbols meant anything; it would be nice to find out that they did. λ seems an odd choice for an integer... in many other contexts it gets used as a real number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how relevant this is outside of Ireland, but while doing basic mechanics, if you ever see acceleration denoted as $f$, as it is in the "log tables" here, as in $v=u+ft$, the $f$ in this case stands for the Latin for acceleration, festinatio (with festino meaning "I hurry", so festinatio would very roughly and more literally translate as "hurriedness"), which is funny because adcelero is the Latin for "I speed up" which looks a lot more like acceleration.

Similarly, displacement denoted by $s$ as in $s=ut+\frac12 at^2$ is from the Latin for displacement, summoveo (with moveo meaning "I move [something]").

And, of course, velocitas, the Latin for speed. I can imagine u being used for velocity as well since the Romans actually pronounced "v" as "u", so the two are pretty much interchangeable.