# Why is the identity element of a group denoted by $e$?

Tags: ho.history-overview, notation

The question was asked by a student, and I did not have a ready answer. I can think of the German word ``Einheit'', but since in German that is not how the identity element of a group is called, I doubt that is the origin. Any ideas?

Comment: "but since in German that is not how the identity element of a group is called" ... Sometimes it is indeed called like this. Also the identity matrix is frequently or at least not rarely called 'Einheitsmatrix'. Another thought: Sometimes the identity element in a multiplicative group is called (perhaps sloppily) Einselement (where 'eins' means 'one').   

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Heinrich Weber uses Einheit and e in his Lehrbuch der Algebra (1896).

Comment: That is almost certainly the origin, though it should be noted that one in Russian is "edinica".

Comment: @Igor: The influential early textbooks on algebra tended to be written in German, unfair though that may be to those of us who grew up with English (or Russian).    Quite a bit of common terminology and notation in mathematics seems to have originated in German work during the 19th century, such as the symbols `$K,k$` for fields.      

Comment: Well, Weber surely popularized the term.  But his friend  Dedekind used "einheit" before him to mean either a unit in a field, or a unit measure in geometry, and I'll bet if you look in his work you'll find it for groups.  Probably if you dig into the 19th century you can find a series of earlier and earlier, vaguer and vaguer, uses of the term for a group identity. 

Comment: In todays German literature, it seems that *Einselement* (or even *neutrales Element*) is preferred over *Einheit* (which is used for units, i.e. invertible elements of a ring).

Answer (score 19):

The *Encyklopädie* article of Heinrich Burkhardt, [*Endliche discrete Gruppen* (1899), p. 218](https://archive.org/stream/encyklomath101encyrich#page/n263) ascribes the origin thus:

> **15. Allgemeiner Gruppenbegriff.** (...) die Gruppe enthält ein
>   Element $e$, die *Einheit* $^{73)}$, das mit jedem andern $a$ $ae = a$ und $ea = a$
>   ergiebt; (...)
>
> ---
>
> 73) (...) *G. Frobenius* u. *E. Stickelberger*, J. f. Math. 86, 1879[78], p. 219.

The paper in question, [*Ueber Gruppen von vertauschbaren Elementen*](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0086&PHYSID=phys224) (1879), reads:

> **§.1. Definitionen.**
>
> Die Elemente unserer Untersuchung sind die $\varphi(\mathbf M)$ Klassen von (reellen) ganzen Zahlen, welche in Bezug auf einen Modul $\mathbf M$ incongruent und relativ prim zu demselben sind. (...) Das Element $\mathbf E$  (so bezeichnen wir im folgenden die Zahlenklasse, deren Repräsentant 1 ist) heisst das *Hauptelement*.

Comment: I'm confused. So, the conclusion is that the choice of E by Frobenius and Stickelberger is unmotivated (as their term for the unit is Hauptelement), and its identification with Einheit by later researchers (such as Burkhardt) is a false etymology?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I agree that without further evidence of the transition, it's hard to tell how influential F & S's (pervasively used) ***E*** was in the eventual choice of *e*. They do tie it with *eins* insofar as their term for the unit is also *Klasse von 1* (in quote above).

Comment: For German speakers: am I missing something, or does Burkhardt's Encyklopädie really define a "group" as a cancellative semigroup, and then claim that the existence of the unit and inverses follow?

Comment: @Tobias Fritz: No. First they define group as a group of permutations: "Hat eine Gesamtheit von Substitutionen die Eigenschaft, dass jedes Produkt von irgend zweien derselben selbst in ihr enthalten ist, so heisst sie eine Gruppe." (p. 211: Has a set of substitutions the property that every product of any two of them is again in this set, then this set is called a group). Then on p. 217, they define a general group by giving the axioms for a cancelative semigroup, and then state that if in addition the group is finite, inverses and an identity exist.

Answer (score -1):

The identity element for a complex number is (1,0)=1.
The german word for "one" is "eins" so we write e.

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrales_Element

Comment: this seems speculative, compared with the sources quoted by Francois Ziegler